# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfingerprint'"

Tags: python, module, python-3.7, fingerprint

I'm new to this coding and all I did was copying this instruction:
https://sicherheitskritisch.de/2015/03/fingerprint-sensor-fuer-den-raspberry-pi-und-debian-linux-en/

When I reach at the testing part I get this error:

```
from  pyfingerprint.pyfingerprint import PyFingerprint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfingerprint'
```

btw. I am using Raspberry Pi 3, running Python 3.7.3
and fingerprint scanner used is U.are.U 4500 Digital Persona

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the part of installing the `python-fingerprint` package from the tutorial you shared. Try installing it.

```
$ echo "deb http://apt.pm-codeworks.de wheezy main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ wget -O - http://apt.pm-codeworks.de/pm-codeworks.de.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install python-fingerprint
```

Comment: I have done those already. even rebooting after the installation

Comment: @PG15 I see you are using `python 3`. Try following the installation instructions here for `python3`: https://github.com/bastianraschke/pyfingerprint

Comment: so far the installation went well, altho i got another error.. "The fingerprint sensor could not be initialized! Exception message: The fingerprint sensor port "/dev/ttyUSB0" was not found!"

This error appeared when i used the command "Enroll a new Finger"

Comment: @PG15 that seems like a known-issue. The debugging help for the same has been given in the tutorial. Give a look at the same.

Comment: as i read through the FAQ. (https://sicherheitskritisch.de/2015/03/fingerprint-sensor-fuer-den-raspberry-pi-und-debian-linux-en/) regarding the error. I believe i may have gotten the wrong fingerprint model... altho is there any chance or a way to bypass this? I am using a U.are.U 4500 Digital Personal Model.

Comment: @PG15 you can't bypass that. That's the libray interface. You need to talk to the `python-fingerprint` library developers.